# How to remove Field Group module label length limit?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

How to remove Field Group module label length limit (which is 128 characters). Is there any module to change the default length?

Comment: Well, if you check the module's table, the limit is also set there. So removing limit on form would not help alone. You have to modify the storage length as well! You can achieve extending length of the field on form using hook_form_alter!

Answer (score 0):

hook_form_alter() 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

Will allow you to modify the length of the value for the text input but youll also need to

hook_schema_alter()
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7

as well to modify the storage in the db.